# How do I do this in my Django URLs? (.json, .xml)

Tags: python, django, json, http, url

Suppose this is my URL route:

```
(r'^test/?$','hello.life.views.test'),
```

How do I make it so that people can do .json, .xml, and it would pass a variable to my views.test, so that I know to make json or xml?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

to add to @ziang's answer, if you really want to emulate file extensions you could just write the regular expression that way. `r'^test\.(?P<extension>(json)|(xml))$'`

EDIT: I will add that it's certainly more RESTful to provide the expected return content type as a parameter.

Comment: Just a simple note: you can use `(json|xml)` instead of `(json)|(xml)`. I think it's more clear and the meaning is the same.

Comment: @mg. your edit still creates an additional capturing group; which isn't needed.  Albeit easier to read. There's a better way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35436975/615422

Answer (score 0):

Pass xml or json as a parameter. You can catch it in the URL like this (r'^test/(?P < doc_type > [^/]+)$','hello.life.views.test'),

Answer (score 0):

I have implement something similar:

```
 (r'^test$', 'test'), 
 (r'^test/(?P<format>json)$', 'test'),
```

And in views.py, I have something like:

```
def list(request, format="html"):
    if format == 'json':
        ...
    elif format == 'html':
        ...
    ...
```

I have specify two similar url patterns because I want to keep the `extension` part optional, and when ignored the default format (`html` in my case) is used.

It seems like I can't implement this with an optional pattern in regex, because doing something like `(?P<format>json)?` would result in a `None` value and the default value will never be used.

Hope this experience can be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I choose a default (json) for my api.  If the end-developer wants to work against a different format (yaml, xml, etc) I let them send it as a get parameter:

```
http://api.mysite.com/getinfo/?format=xml

def get_info_view(request):
    format = request.GET.get(format, None)
    if format:
        # handle alternate (non-json) format
    return json_object
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the key point to the question is *can*:

> so that people **can** do .json, .xml

Which means the format is optional.

@satoru & @teepark address this as a second `url()` entry. However, why not make it just one with good regex?

## Solution

```
url(r'^test(?:\.(?P<format>json|xml))?$', 'hello.life.views.test', name='test'),
```

Validation: https://regex101.com/r/iQ8gG4/1

Answer (score 0):

Django 3.0

```
re_path('api/test/values\.json', Api.as_view())
```

Work perfectly in my case, url looks like : `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/test/values.json`